# Preventing Windows from shutting down

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows form,I want to display the message to the user that the process is not complete if the user tries to shut down the windows or tries to closes the application before completion of process(the user forgot to complete the process),if the user presses OK i want to stop the window from shutting down and let the user complete the process,I did find some code on the net to do so but it is in VB not in c#

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.WindowsShutDown))
    {
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell("shutdown -a", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, false, -1);
        MessageBox.Show("Shutdown process cancelled!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a big deal, you can include the reference Microsoft.VisualBasic in your C# project.

Comment: Right click on references of your project -> Add reference -> open .NET tab -> find Microsoft.VisualBasic -> click Ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use this piece of code snippet instead, play with `e.Cancel` as per your requirement:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.WindowsShutDown))
    {
       if (MessageBox.Show("You are closing this app.\n\nAre you sure you wish to exit ?", "Warning: Not Submitted", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
           return;    
       else    
           e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Reference: [SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> Occurs when the user is trying to log off or shut down the system.