# Application is preventing Windows from shutting down

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application which starts a couple of background workers and has a main UI thread running a form.

This application sometimes prevents the user from logging off, restarting or shutting down.

It shows a screen like the following:

[image: My Program Preventing windows from shutting down]

The only solution I got is subscribing to the FormClosing event of my mainform and force the closing of the program like shown in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116916/6518812).

Following this solution I was able to terminate my program without waiting indefinitely on the screen shown above but I still get it for few seconds.

How can I prevent the windows from showing

> This program is preventing Windows from (restarting/shutting down/logging off)?

I tried other answers on similar question:

- Made sure all my other threads are background threads
- Subscribed to the Form_Closing event (Partial solution, windows closes the application eventually but the message appears for a few seconds)
- Made sure no other forms are implementing Form_Closing and holding the application

Comment: You're doing the correct thing alright by subscribing to the `FormClosing` event. Why does your application take so long to close though? Perhaps explicitly cleaning up resources from the `FormClosing` event would make it more performant?

Comment: Do you stop the mentioned workers when the program is closed?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer No I'm not stopping the workers because what I understand is that if they are marked as background (isbackground=true), windows will take care of them.

Comment: When you exit the application while running in VisualStudio - does it also take that long for the program to end?